# Stucked screen in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, package, explorer

In Eclipse, when I go to:

(Package Explorer) then to (Resources)-Layout-Right Click-New-Android XML File

a screen asks you to enter the New Android XML file.  Once I've done that and pressed Next, a screen named (Choose Configuration Folder) came up, but whatever I do in that screen, whether I press Next or Finish, nothing happens! The screen is still up! Can anybody tell me the reason for that?

Comment: check your file name if it is proper then RESTART eclipse!!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to add a new xml file generally in the res folder , so make sure you do that and after giving name for your desired xml file , you should select the one of the options below Linear layout, List view .. etc, then click finish . you should be able to get the main screen with your desired xml file

Comment: Actually the problem was with the file name since it started with Capital letter!Thank you vnshetty that solved my problem!